# Swift URL from string with `caffè` in it

Tags: swift, url

I need to create URL from string `https://example.com/media/caffè.mp3`

```
let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/media/caffè.mp3") // fails to create URL
```

But in Safari it works as expected.

How can I encode this string or something to get working URL from it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
let urlString = "https://example.com/media/caffè.mp3".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed) 
let url = URL(string: urlString )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let urlString = "https://example.com/media/caffè.mp3"

let encoded = urlString
      .addingPercentEncoding(
        withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!

let url = URL(string: encoded) // this works
```

Comment: Actually it's `.urlPathAllowed`. *Query* is the part after the question mark.